# HTTP 405 post method not supported by this url

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am to take a question from a HTML page say *"index.jsp"* to a servlet say servlet.java and program it there such that keywords are extracted from the question entered through *index.jsp* and those keywords as output to show in another JSP page say output.jsp. Please see my code and please say me why the error occurs that

```
"http 405: post not supported by this url".
```

I am using tomcat and running it like *localhost:8080\myprograms\index.jsp*
Moreover i have no idea how the *web.xml* must be written what to write in url pattern *\index.jsp* or *\servlet*. Do i need to enter the *output.jsp* page in the *web.xml*

*index.jsp*

---

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>
Query search
</title>
<style>
BODY { background: url(mag.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="1.html">Exit</a>
<img src="home.png" align="left" height="180" width="130"> 
<center>
<form action="servlet1" method="post"></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
<font face="Broadway" color="white" align="left">Search........!!!!</font></br></br>
<input type="text" name="query" size="100"></br></br></br></br>
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit Query">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="RESET" value="Reset">
</form>
</center></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
<font color="white"><marquee behavior="alternate">Note:Only generalized query that starts as "who", "what","give"..</marquee></font>
</body>
</html>
```

*output.jsp*

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Output Page</title>
    </head>
    <body align="center">
        <form method="GET" action="servlet1">
        <p>${z}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

*servlet1.java*

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * @author hp
 */
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/servlet1"})
public class servlet1 extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */


    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
       String txt=request.getParameter("query");
     if (txt.matches("Who is the(.*)")) {
    String re1=".*?";   
    String re2="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   
    String re3=".*?";
    String re4="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   
    String re5=".*?";   
    String re6="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   
    String re7=".*?";   
    String re8="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; 
    String re9=".*?";   
    String re10="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  
    String re11=".*?";  
    String re12="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String word1=m.group(1);
        String word2=m.group(2);
        String z=word2.toString()+"|"+word1.toString()+"\n";
        request.setAttribute("z",z);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/output.jsp").forward(request, response);  
    }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    /*@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //processRequest(request, response);
        doGet(request, response);
    }*/

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this Error as in your servlet , `doPost` method is commented, which will handle your `Post type Request`

```
  /*@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException {
        //processRequest(request, response);
        doGet(request, response);
    }*/
```

Comment: This is the output form on which the results are to be displayed and i have another page named index.jsp from which the input is passed to the servlet and there i hava written " post " . what should i write in my web.xml and why this error plz help

Comment: read my updated answer !   and please google some good tutorials about Servlets and jsp

Comment: Thank you so much it got fixed !!